# Can any one give a screen shot of how and where we can enable /clr:pure option in visual studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, clr

Can any one give a screen shot of how and where we can enable /clr:pure option in C++ project visual studio 2008?

Comment: http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/CommentView.aspx?guid=73a22695-63a3-4ceb-9478-27c33abba940